# C++ Linker error when using O1 optimization

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, compiler-optimization

In an already existing and quite large project, I'm enabling the gcc compiler optimization `O1`.

Without this option, everything builds, links and runs fine.
with the option enabled, the main executable compiles and links, but I get linker errors when linking one of the unit tests.

Between these 2 compile runs, I didn't change any code or make files, only the `O1` optimization flag.

The error that I get is:

```
Configuration.a(Builder.o): In function `Builder::Create() const':
Builder.cpp:123: undefined reference to `Factory::Instance()'
```

Somewhere during the linking process, it encounters this line (line 123) of `Builder.cpp`:
cpp file

```
pObject = Factory::Instance()->CreateObject();
```

(Besides the linker error of the `Instance` function, I also get one from the `CreateObject` function)

When I look at the `Factory`, I see:
header file

```
class Factory { public:
    static Factory* Instance(); << rest of the file >>
```

And in the cpp file

```
Factory* Factory::sInstance = 0;

Factory* Factory::Instance() {
    // Check if this is the first call
    if (sInstance == 0)
    {
        // Create only instance
        sInstance = new Factory();
    }

    // Address of the instance
    return sInstance; }
```

First I tried a clean and rebuild, but that didn't do anything.
also I used nm to make dumps of the used symbols of `Factory.o` (one with and one without optimization) and compared these.

I see that some symbols are removed, but not the `Factory::Instance()` one. I do see something with the address changed regarding this function, but I won't expect that to be a problem.

Also via Google I found a couple of possibilities, but I couldn't find something that matched my problem.

does anyone have an idea of how to find this problem?

Comment: Compiler version? How do you compile it (is the makefile short enough to post?) ? Have you made sure that it's the only thing you changed (ie, if you take the `-O1` back out, does it compile again)?

Comment: Apart from lacking thread-safety and misleading naming (`Factory` is really rather something like a singleton), I see nothing objectionable in the code you showed. If `-O1` is really the only thing you changed, this should work just fine. Unless there is a conditional clause in the makefile that doesn't compile `factory.cpp` or something when optimizations are turned on, but that would be a bit ridiculous (can pretty much rule that out!).

Answer (score 1):

> Configuration.a(Builder.o): In function `Builder::Create() const':
>   Builder.cpp:123: undefined reference to`Factory::Instance()'

Since you've verified that `Factory::Instance()` *is* defined in `Factory.o`, and since you are obviously using archive libraries, my crystal ball says that whatever library contains `Factory.o` is on command line *before* `Configuration.a`, whereas it should be *after* it.

The order of archive libraries on command line [matters](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).